# migration problem while hosting a django project on PythonAnywhere

Tags: django, database, postgresql, pythonanywhere

I recently finished my django project and i switched my database from the local SQLite database, provided by django, to an online postgreSQL database provided by elephantSQL. Clearly, by entering my database credential in the setings.py file of my django project i am able to migrate to my new database locally while not on my host's bash console. Meaning that, when i run my server on port 8000 it loads my data from the postgreSQL, but when i push my website to PythonAnywhere and try to run my migrations from the bash console of PythonAnywhere it throws out the following error:`

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: connection to server at "'USER'.db.elephantsql.com" ("DATABASE_IP"), port 5432 failed: Connection refused
        Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```

`

I even changed my database Host from elephanSQL to nhost, but still it promps the same result.

Comment: Are you using a free account on PythonAnywhere?  Free accounts there can only access external resources over HTTP or HTTPS, and are limited to specific whitelisted sites (https://www.pythonanywhere.com/whitelist/), so you won't be able to connect to an external Postgres database.   You'd need a paid account for that.

Comment: yes i am. but elephantSQl.com is already in the whitelisted websites that you just attached the link. so, does it mean that regardless of the site being whitelisted it still uses HTTP or HTTPS? Then what is the reasoning behind having a whitelist of 1000 websites?

Comment: @Billy yes, only HTTP(S) is allowed for free accounts. Also `customer.elephantsql.com` and `api.elephantsql.com` are whitelisted, not `db.elephantsql.com` which is what you are using. As to the reason of having a whitelist see: https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/RequestingWhitelistAdditions/